Problem with `flutter_cache_manager` package in Android
I am using flutter_cache_manager to cache downloaded files (file size is about 40mb), the code is working perfectly in iOS:
Future<String?> fetchModel() async {
  try {
    final cacheManager = getIt<DefaultCacheManager>();
    final model = await cacheManager.getSingleFile(modelUrl);

    return model.path;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }

  return null;
}

However, I am getting this error on Android:
Error: Unable to load asset: "/data/user/0/com.app_name/cache/libCachedImageData/d02ec560-b3ea-11ef-9165-eb544f5951c5.bin".

The asset does not exist or has empty data.

PlatformAssetBundle.load.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:327:9)

